# Problem reading multiple json files and make dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I try to make a dataframe reading  multiple json files but the program reads only one of those files. I get the data I want to but only from this one file. Do you know how can I read all these files and concatenate them to make one DataFrame? I get no errors when I run this program.
Here is the code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import os



path = 'C:\\Users\\sotir\\Desktop\\machinedataset'

filenames = os.listdir(path)
for filename in sorted(filenames):
    if filename.startswith("mpd.slice") and filename.endswith(".json"):
        fullpath = os.sep.join((path, filename))
        f = open(fullpath)
        js = json.load(f)
        f.close()


df= pd.json_normalize(js['playlists'], meta=['name', 'collaborative', 'pid', 'modified_at','num_tracks', 'num_albums', 
                                              'num_followers', 'num_edits', 'duration_ms', 'num_artists'],record_path= ['tracks'],
                       record_prefix='_')
```

Here is a part of one json file:

```
{
    "info": {
        "generated_on": "2017-12-03 08:41:42.057563", 
        "slice": "0-999", 
        "version": "v1"
    }, 
    "playlists": [
        {
            "name": "Throwbacks", 
            "collaborative": "false", 
            "pid": 0, 
            "modified_at": 1493424000, 
            "num_tracks": 52, 
            "num_albums": 47, 
            "num_followers": 1, 
            "tracks": [
                {
                    "pos": 0, 
                    "artist_name": "Missy Elliott", 
                    "track_uri": "spotify:track:0UaMYEvWZi0ZqiDOoHU3YI", 
                    "artist_uri": "spotify:artist:2wIVse2owClT7go1WT98tk", 
                    "track_name": "Lose Control (feat. Ciara & Fat Man Scoop)", 
                    "album_uri": "spotify:album:6vV5UrXcfyQD1wu4Qo2I9K", 
                    "duration_ms": 226863, 
                    "album_name": "The Cookbook"
                }, 
                {
                    "pos": 1, 
                    "artist_name": "Britney Spears", 
                    "track_uri": "spotify:track:6I9VzXrHxO9rA9A5euc8Ak", 
                    "artist_uri": "spotify:artist:26dSoYclwsYLMAKD3tpOr4", 
                    "track_name": "Toxic", 
                    "album_uri": "spotify:album:0z7pVBGOD7HCIB7S8eLkLI", 
                    "duration_ms": 198800, 
                    "album_name": "In The Zone"
                }, 
                
            ], 
            "num_edits": 6, 
            "duration_ms": 11532414, 
            "num_artists": 37
        },
```

Comment: The way your code is structured, the line `df=pd.normalize(...)` only runs after the loop through the filenames is completely finished. Meaning that `js` will only contain the contents of the very last file in the loop. It seems like you'd have to create the `df` beforehand and then update it with each `js`.

Comment: Do all of those Json files have the same structure?

Comment: yes the structure is the same

Answer (score 0):

Inside your for loop you need to append the loaded data for example to a list and then start to build your dataframe from the loaded data.

```
data = [] # Here is your list
filenames = os.listdir(path)
for filename in sorted(filenames):
    if filename.startswith("mpd.slice") and filename.endswith(".json"):
        fullpath = os.sep.join((path, filename))
        f = open(fullpath)
        data.append(json.load(f)) # here data keeps the loaded json
        f.close()
```

After that you can use data list to build your datafrme

Comment: Thanks for your response, I updated my code but I get an error. I added the code as an answer.